# Удаленное редактирование исходных файлов на сервере с удаленными пользователями

Tags: remote-access

Как организовать работу двух программистов удаленно, которые подключены к удаленному серверу и на нем редактируют и дополняют своим кодом.
Конечно я пробовал организовать с помощью дополнения Live Share к Visual Studio Code, однако необходимо чтобы файлы были не у одного пользователя, а на удаленном сервере.

Может кто-то таким занимался и что вообще можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В том же VS Code есть дополнение [Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview). Оно позволяет подключатся к удалённой машине по SSH или WSL (протоколы удалённого доступа), и в последующем взаимодействовать с удалённым компьютером (терминал, файловая система) так будто ты просто открыл проект в VS Code на локальном компьютере. Использую его на своём ноуте что бы подключаться к домашнему компьютеру когда лень настраивать окружение. Хотя лучше для синхронизации программистов всё же использовать git

Comment: На удалённом компьютере понадобится настроить SSH https://dev.to/zduey/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-server-on-a-home-computer